# Разное выравнивание на разных экранах

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

Есть 2 блока которые на больших экранах нужно отобразить в один ряд с выравниванием содержимого по левому краю, а на маленьких в два ряда и с выравниванием по центру. Как это можно реализовать с помощью bootstrap или еще как. Спасибо!

Comment: Все же написано в документации, расписана каждая мелочь с кучей примеров, да еще и на русский переведена. [Открываем](http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) и читаем

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align">Блок 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 align">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

css

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) and (max-width : 1200px)   
 {
    .align {text-align:left;}
 } 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
    .align {text-align:center;}
 } 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .align {text-align:center;}
 }
```

Comment: Я не правильно выразился. Я имел ввиду выравнивание содержимого блоков.

Comment: @Karaaa006 поправил

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper .block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center
}

@media screen (min-width: 900px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex
  }
  .wrapper .block {
    text-align: left
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
</div>
```